# Brand new ASP .NET Core Web app gives 404 errors

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

I am running Visual Studio 2022 and have a .NET web app that has been working perfectly for quite some time. I got a new laptop about a month ago and have a clean install of everything and it has been working fine. Today this site started giving 404 errors for every page:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7066/
HTTP ERROR 404
```

So I tried creating a brand new site and it also does the same thing. I'm guessing it is a problem with IISExpress but not sure how to diagnose or repair?

Answer (score 1):

Did a complete uninstall of visual studio and iisexpress and reinstalled and now it is working again.